# Semantic ui with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, simple-form, semantic-ui

tell me how to configure simple_form. I would like to use the checkbox of semantic ui, but when I wrap checkbox in the class, he becomes active, that is, visually it is, but when you click the check box is not activated.

```
    = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
     .ui.three.column.middle.aligned.relaxed.grid.basic.segment
       .column
       .column
       .column
         .ui.form.segment
           #marg.field= f.label :email, 'Email'
           #marg.field=f.input :email, placeholder: 'Email', autofocus: true, label: false
           #marg.field= f.label :password, 'Пароль'
           = f.input :password, :required => false, placeholder: 'Пароль', label: false
           #marg.ui.toggle.checkbox
             = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
           #marg= f.button :submit, 'Войти!', class: 'small ui blue submit button'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACJeL.png

Comment: `= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline` Please try it

Comment: can I make a post and expect an acceptance from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it

```
= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline
```

Comment: I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do this is to create a custom simple form wrapper. Here is a blogpost which describes how to add the wrapper: http://pranavsingh.me/semantic-ui-simple-form-wrapper/

The above configuration will automatically add all the essential classes semantic form classes, and also adds wrappers to create proper checkbox fields. Below is an example:

```
= f.input :published, label: "Published?",
hint: "If you are not ready to go live yet, keep this site unpublished.",
wrapper: :ui_toggle_checkbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do (the accepted answer got me on the right track, but didn't fully fix the issue):

In the *config/initializers/simple_form.rb* file, change

```
config.boolean_style = :nested
```

to

```
config.boolean_style = :inline
```

This prevents Simple Form from wrapping the input tag in the label tag (essentially inserting a tag between the '.ui .checkbox' div and the input, which breaks Semantic's checkbox functionality).

In the *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* file:

```
$('.ui.checkbox').find('input').checkbox();
```

My form now displays checkboxes correctly and passes the appropriate value when submitted.

---

#### Here is another option (to just fix one checkbox) -

In a *_form.html.erb* partial:

```
<div class="inline field">
  <div class="ui checkbox">
    <%= my_form.input :my_input, label: 'My Label', as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the *application.js* file:

```
$('.ui.checkbox').find('input').checkbox();
```